# Как взять значение <p> или id нажатой <button> с помощью ESP8266WebServer

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

на сайте пользователь нажимает на одну из кнопок со своим id, после чего ему высвечивается окно с
вопросом "точно это id". можно ли передать на ESP значение

```
<p name="n">
```

используя ESP8266WebServer сейчас у меня такой код для передачи значений

```
String get_data(String web_name){
      if(server.args()>0){
    for(int i = 0;i<server.args();i++){
      if(server.argName(i)==web_name){
         data = server.arg(i);
         break;
      }
      delay(200);
    }
  }
  
  return data;
     };
```

но он не работает.

и ещё вопрос можно-ли как то передать id нажатой

```
<a>
```

в esp?

Comment: Не могу говорить конретно про esp Server, но для того чтобы получить id нажатой кнопки, вы можете использовать javascript или его фреймворк Jquery. P.S можно узнать что вы хотите сделать на ESP 8266?

Comment: если про сам проект , то хочу сделать месенджер , понимаю , что идея глупая , наверное , так как WiFi Slot может за раз отвечать лишь одному пользователю, но просто интересно попробовать

Comment: а про id кнопки, я могу его получить, но не знаю как перенести его на сам ESP

Comment: Понимаю, пытался рендерить 4к сцены на ардуино нано) А если принципиально именно на своём железе, можно юзать ethernet разъем для ардуино или stm, или Rasberry

Comment: `а про id кнопки`, понял. Удачи)

Comment: спасибо, она мне пригодится